# how to insert duplicated rows with adding some modification using shell commands?

Tags: shell

I have a bunch of data as below.

```
1,A9600,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime    
2,A9600,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
3,A9600,003_LIT,NA,TIME,startTime
4,A9600,004_ETC,NA,TIME,startTime
5,B9600,005_CMP,NA,TIME,startTime
6,B9600,006_IMP,NA,TIME,startTime
7,B9600,007_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime
```

and I want them to be modified as below.

```
1,A9600,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime
1,A9600_1,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime
1,A9600_2,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime
1,A9600_3,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime  
2,A9600,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
2,A9600_1,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
2,A9600_2,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
2,A9600_3,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
....
```

How to achieve this using shell commands?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Which shell are you using?  Do you mean only  shell commands, or others like (for example) `awk`?

Comment: awk is also fine with me. I am using bash shell on centOS. awk,sed or anything else in shell scripts is fine.

Comment: But I want to make it using loop clause. because typing specific number will be a time consuming task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk one-liner works for this problem. You can just change the `c` variable to get different looping times.

```
 awk -F',' -v c='3' -v OFS="," '7;{old=$2;for(i=1;i<=c;i++){$2=old"_"i;print}}' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What `7` and  `$2` means for in above statement?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl solution, Maybe it needs more enhancement but this is what I have got (any updates are very welcome :D)

```
cat file | perl -ne 'print "$_" x4' | perl -pe '$c++; $c eq 1 ? s/([a-zA-Z]\d+)/$1/g : s/([a-zA-Z]\d+)/$1_${\($c - 1)}/g;$c eq 4 ? $c=0: $c=$c'
```

**`file` should contain the following:**

```
1,A9600,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime    
2,A9600,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
3,A9600,003_LIT,NA,TIME,startTime
4,A9600,004_ETC,NA,TIME,startTime
5,B9600,005_CMP,NA,TIME,startTime
6,B9600,006_IMP,NA,TIME,startTime
7,B9600,007_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime
```

**The output will be the following:**

```
1,A9600,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime    
1,A9600_1,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime    
1,A9600_2,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime    
1,A9600_3,001_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime    
2,A9600,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
2,A9600_1,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
2,A9600_2,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
2,A9600_3,002_DEP,NA,TIME,startTime
3,A9600,003_LIT,NA,TIME,startTime
3,A9600_1,003_LIT,NA,TIME,startTime
3,A9600_2,003_LIT,NA,TIME,startTime
3,A9600_3,003_LIT,NA,TIME,startTime
4,A9600,004_ETC,NA,TIME,startTime
4,A9600_1,004_ETC,NA,TIME,startTime
4,A9600_2,004_ETC,NA,TIME,startTime
4,A9600_3,004_ETC,NA,TIME,startTime
5,B9600,005_CMP,NA,TIME,startTime
5,B9600_1,005_CMP,NA,TIME,startTime
5,B9600_2,005_CMP,NA,TIME,startTime
5,B9600_3,005_CMP,NA,TIME,startTime
6,B9600,006_IMP,NA,TIME,startTime
6,B9600_1,006_IMP,NA,TIME,startTime
6,B9600_2,006_IMP,NA,TIME,startTime
6,B9600_3,006_IMP,NA,TIME,startTime
7,B9600,007_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime
7,B9600_1,007_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime
7,B9600_2,007_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime
7,B9600_3,007_DIF,NA,TIME,startTime
```

**Explanation:**

`perl -ne 'print "$_" x4'`: this part is responsible for duplicating each line in `file` according to `x4` which will print each line 4 times

`perl -pe '$c++; $c eq 1 ? s/([a-zA-Z]\d+)/$1/g : s/([a-zA-Z]\d+)/$1_${\($c - 1)}/g;$c eq 4 ? $c=0: $c=$c'`: this part is responsible for finding the `A9600` , `B9600`,..etc pattern using this regex `[a-zA-Z]\d+` and then append `_n` to it according to the value of `$c` which will be set to 0 each 4 times to avoid counting more than what we need.